# oracle 10g - ORA00257

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, errors

is there any way to recover from a ORA-00257: archiver error?

The archiver disks broke, but DB continue operation 2 sequences more.
I have no access to the archiver disk anymore

```
 SQL> archive log list
Database log mode              Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Enabled
Archive destination            /drbak/arch/terdb/pro/va
Oldest online log sequence     46612
Next log sequence to archive   46612
Current log sequence           46614




SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest;
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 50000M


SQL> SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SPACE_LIMIT SPACE_USED SPACE_RECLAIMABLE NUMBER_OF_FILES
----------- ---------- ----------------- ---------------

 5.2429E+10          0                 0               0
```

Comment: thank you Phil....you think that the same solution applies? i mean in this case i have no access at all to the archiver disk...and i dont have Flash_recovery_area enabled...

Answer (score 1):

If your existing archive location is no longer available, change it to one that is:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 = ('LOCATION=<new location>');
```

You'll want to take a Level 0 backup immediately afterwards. With missing archivelogs, your database is no longer recoverable.

Comment: actually, log_archive_dest_1 makes reference to a directory that exists and have space remainig...because the fail disk was mounted on that directory in the server...now is empty

Comment: ah, so the archiver is trying to write to a file that doesn't exist? @Phil's solution from the linked thread shoud work then.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thank you, the solution works with a little fix before...

when i ran `alter system archive log all;`

i obtain a

```
ORA-16020: less destinations available than specified by LOG_ARCHIVE_MIN_SUCCEED_DEST
```

my value is:
`log_archive_min_succeed_dest         integer     1` 
 and the destination state seems fine:

```
log_archive_dest_state_1             string      ENABLE
```

so seems stuck... and i found a solution for this in 
  http://www.acehints.com/2011/06/troubleshoot-fix-resolve-ora-00257.html ...

so:

```
alter system set LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 = 'location=/arch/terdb/pro reopen';
alter system archive log all;
alter system switch logfile;
```

... and now the issue is solved, but the parameter for LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 remains in this value... that makes me doubt: 'location=/arch/terdb/pro reopen';